# Howto check if user is part of any roles?

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I'm working with Websecurity and roles and i'm trying to solve an issue i have.

When you create a new account you do not get asign any role in Websecurity and i want to take care of that so someone who is not part of any roles can't login to the page.
i'm using `if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)` to check if the account exist and if you logged in correctly but i would also like the page to check if the user is part of any role e.g and if they are the next step is to check if they are apart of correct role for that page.

I have searched for this way of authenticate userole but not found any. And hoping someone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: Anything wrong with the standard `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SubAdmin")]` type decorations on controllers/actions?

Comment: The thing is that if you create a new login it wont set a role by default, so what i do want is that if you are not part of a role X will be displayed. I have not found any solution to this.

Comment: Why not add an initial role ie. "guest" when the account is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to implement the security of your website, then you can read the tutorial provided on the ASP.NET Web Pages official website, they have a well written set of tutorial in their hands.

Secondly, the piece of code that you're sharing

```
if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Would only check for the LoggedIn property of the user, it wouldn't check whether user has account, role etc. It would check for a cookie or cache that was set by the Server when the user logged in using

```
WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
```

This way, you can only check whether user was logged in or not. If is used to show

> **Login | Register** or **user_name | Sign out**

banners in the website.

If you want to add a new layer of security to check the roles of the user. Use this

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("roleString")) {
    // user is in the role
} else {
    // user was in no role
}
```

You can append this method inside your `IsAuthenticated` method check to create a 2 layer security.

Example system to check this would be

```
if(WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
   // User is logged in!
   if(Roles.IsUserInRole("someString")) {
      // user is in role
      // check other condition here...I was not able to understand
      // the page condition...Sorry! 
   }
}
```

### EDIT (Check for the newly created users)

When you add a user in Roles. ASP.NET actually creates a new row for that user, with the role that he is in.

It would be something like

```
UserId | RoleId
10     | 1
```

Lets suppose the new created userId is `10` and the RoleId for **Admin** is 1. You can query that, using this

```
var isInRoles = db.Query("SELECT * FROM webpages_UsersInRoles WHERE UserId =@0", 
                WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Count();
if(isInRoles == 0) {
   // No record found! So user must be a New User!
   // Show X here...:)
}
```

This is an example to check for the user in roles. Or to check whether user is a new user or a previous one and so on.

Comment: yes this i have read but it indicate that you are allready part of a role. But my question is if you are not part of any role at all (fresh account created) then X will be displayed.

Comment: @Tman, I have added more details to the answer! :) You can check it now, I hope it would be enough for you to understand...

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial on [Adding Security and Membership to an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership) from the Asp.Net site proposes this way to test if the user owns the admin role:

```
@if ( Roles.IsUserInRole("admin")) {
    <span> Welcome <b>@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</b>! </span>
}
else {
    Response.Redirect("~/AdminError");
}
```

**Edited**

If you want to test if the current user hasn't any role you could try something like:

```
@if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName).Length == 0){
    // user has no role
} else {
    // user has at least one role
}
```

Comment: Yes i have read this before but im looking for a solution if you're not part of any role at all.